#  Cached hidden input value is being used in IE9 instead of updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, hidden-field

I have an issue with IE9 using the initial value of my hidden input element instead of the dynamically updated value.

I have created the following so that you can see my issue live: http://jsfiddle.net/NN8gM/

- The page loads, and the hidden input value is displayed. When the
  value is updated dynamically (by clicking the checkbox in the
  example), the initial value (6.00) is still being displayed in IE
  instead of the new value (7.00)!

The updated value is being displayed correctly in other browsers i have tried. Run the example in firefox to see the desired effect.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing it the normal way and using:

```
$('#si').attr('value', '7.00');
```

Comment: That actually works (well, without the .next()), the problem is i'm not able to use `$('#si')` because that would assume it is unique. So the problem is using:
`$(this).next()`
Why does this work in firefox etc, but not in IE9

Comment: It's Internet Explorer, whaddya expect?

Comment: Haha.. True. I'm new to this game and I'm already learning that the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code in ie9, one thing i would like to tell you, its not true that its picking the cached value,

actually this code is not working `$(this).next().attr('value', '7.00');`

i replaced that part of your code with `$('input[type=hidden]').attr('value', '7.00');`
and it worked fine, below is a demo.

I am still figuring out why the code you have written works in mozilla not in ie9. (actaully its very tough to debug in ie9, it almost doesnt even open)

http://jsfiddle.net/NN8gM/9/

Comment: Hmm.. Very strange. As above with @Kwpolska, both solutions work. I guess it's more important to work out why `$(this).next().attr('value', '7.00');` works in other browsers but not in ie. The reason why the `.next()` is important is because there are many inputs with the id "si". I need to dynamically update only **one** of them (which is **next** to the triggering button).